# How to make first entry blank in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift

I tried finding an example for this, but all the semi-relevant examples seem to use static data for the `UIPickerView`, and that doesn't fit my circumstance.

I have a `UIPickerView` object which gets its data from a database (core data in this case) - the picker is associated with a text field. The objective is to be able to select an existing entry from the picker or be able to create a new entry that gets added to the picker for the next time the app is run. In general, this is all working fine - except for one part: When the app first loads, the text field is blank (*desired*) but the picker view shows the first existing value selected (***not*** desired)

How can I add a blank entry at the beginning of the picker without having such an entry in the database?

I tried adding the following to my `viewDidLoad()`, but it didn't seem to make any difference:

```
picker.selectRow(-1, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 4):

try something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let entries = ["First", "Second", "Third"]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return entries.count + 1 // +1 for the empty entry
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return row == 0 ? "" : entries[row - 1]
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to leave me with an exception being thrown: `2016-08-16 18:02:11.955 CoreDataDemo[9829:1237496] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'` - somewhere the decrement of 'row' doesn't seem to be happening correctly

Comment: I figured out where the problem was - so your proposed solution **does** work - thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andre - the resulting code worked (I got rid of the `picker.selectRow(-1, inComponent: 0, animated: false)`):

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    let rows = _getNumDataRows() // I had reasons for pulling this out
    return rows + 1 // <<<=== MODIFIED AS PER SUGGESTION
}

func _getNumDataRows() -> Int {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contacts", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
        return results.count
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        status.text = error.localizedFailureReason
    }
    print("UNABLE TO FIND ROWS")
    return 0
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return row == 0 ? "" : _getSelectedValue(row - 1) // <<<=== MODIFIED AS PER SUGGESTION
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    name.text = row == 0 ? "" : _getSelectedValue(row - 1) // <<<=== MODIFIED AS PER SUGGESTION
}

func _getSelectedValue(row: Int) -> String {
    print("Selected Row: \(row)")
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contacts", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
        return results[row].valueForKey("name") as! String
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        status.text = error.localizedFailureReason
    }
    print("NO RECORDS FOUND")
    return ""

}
```